# java derby database batch load from CSV

Tags: java, database, csv, derby

Does Derby have any capabilities from performing a batch insert of data from a CSV? The best I could come up with was to read in the file line by line and create a batch SQL update statement and run that. For 1 million rows that took between 30-40 minutes, as compared with using mySQL's LOAD statement to load from a CSV file which took 2-3 seconds for the same data

Answer (score 7, accepted):

syscs_util.syscs_import_table will do what you want. Here's the docs: http://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.5/tools/rtoolsimport91458.html#rtoolsimport91458