# How to loop a prepared statement to a derby database from spreadsheet line items

Tags: java, derby

Is there a way to enter recurring data into a set database fields while using the prepared statement (pst)? I’m using the Derby DB.

I have an Excel spreadsheet that I get data from. Each line has 5 entry fields: Line item description, cost, quantity, extended cost, and price. I want to enter that into the derby db using just the five entries but with multiple lines each having five entries off the spreadsheet. The database has the following fields: 
    MATLINEITEM     varchar 200
    MATLINEITEMCOST     varchar 7
    MATLINEITEMQTY  varchar 7
    MATLINEITEMXCOST    varchar 7
    MATLINEITEMPRICE    varchar 7

Using the standard INSERT with “ ?” approach, I would need to have an entry for each line and each spreadsheet field. If I have 10 lines, then I would need 50 “prepared statement” lines. I want to just use a loop to read each line and the five entries assigned to that line and enter it into the database.

The data from the spreadsheet is first converted to String (using POI) and assigned to a TextField.

```
addSQL = "INSERT INTO MATERIALTBL (MATLINEITEM, MATLINEITEMCOST, 
   MATLINEITEMQTY, MATLINEITEMXCOST, MATLINEITEMPRICE) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?) ";

   pst = conn.prepareStatement(addSQL);

  pst.setString(1,jtxtfld_Item.getText());
  pst.setString(2,jtxtfld_Cost.getText());
  pst.setString(3,jtxtfld_Qty.getText());
  pst.setString(4,jtxtfld_XCost.getText());
  pst.setString(5,jtxtfld_Price.getText());

  pst.executeUpdate();
```

Any help would be appreciated. Or point me in the right direction as to what I can be using to get this result. Thank you.

Comment: Derby can directly import data from a Comma-Separated-Value file (*.csv), see https://stackoverflow.com/a/2339690/193453

Answer (score 0):

If you want to insert multiple INSERT statements, **it is possible.**

use `addBatch()` and `executeBatch()` methods of `PrepearedStamement`.

You create a `PrepearedStatement`, and add batches to it, until it is ready to be inserted into the database.

## Example

```
String addSQL = "INSERT INTO MATERIALTBL (MATLINEITEM, MATLINEITEMCOST, 
       MATLINEITEMQTY, MATLINEITEMXCOST, MATLINEITEMPRICE) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?) ";
    PreparedStatemen pst = conn.prepareStatement(addSQL);

    //Set auto-commit to false
    conn.setAutoCommit(false);

for (int i = 0; i < amountOfIterations; i++){
    // Set the variables
    pst.setString(1,jtxtfld_Item.getText());
    pst.setString(2,jtxtfld_Cost.getText());
    pst.setString(3,jtxtfld_Qty.getText());
    pst.setString(4,jtxtfld_XCost.getText());
    pst.setString(5,jtxtfld_Price.getText());
    // Add it to the batch
    pst.addBatch();
   } 
    //Create an int[] to hold returned values
    int[] count = stmt.executeBatch();

    //Explicitly commit statements to apply changes
    conn.commit();
```

## Why Use Batches?

This `PrepearedStatement` will be sent only once to the database, and will insert all your rows at once, saving you unnecessary calls to the database.

Comment: Thanks. Obviously I still need to identify each of the variables in the entries --but you did answer my question. I was not familiar with the .addBatch(). see https://www.tutorialspoint.com/jdbc/jdbc-batch-processing.htm for how the variables are defined. (tried to up the score but it wouldn't let me).

Comment: @user1908358 you can select the answer as the correct answer aside from upvoting, it’s helps out as well